# C# WPF SQL SELECT INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, join, inner-join

Im trying to join a user table to retrieve the users login name.
I wish to have TWO INNER joins one for `CreatedByUser_loginname` and `ModifiedByUser_loginname`

But at the moment Im just trying to get the SQL query string syntax right.
BUT, When I change the name of the INNER JOIN with an AS 'name' I get an exception thrown when sqlreader() method is executed. If I remove the AS ... It works, but then I'm unable to add the second INNER JOIN to the same User table to get the name of the modifiedbyuser login name.

Here's the offending code

This doesnt work

```
String sqlComStr = "SELECT Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_Address1, Company_Address2, Company_Address3, Company_Suburb, Company_City, " +
    "Company_State, Company_PostCode, Company_Phone, Company_Fax, Company_WebsiteUrl, Company_Status, Company_ModifiedByUser_ID, Company_CreatedByUser_ID, " +
    " [U1].User_LoginName " +
    "FROM Company INNER JOIN [User] AS U1 ON [User].User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID WHERE [Company].isDeleted = 0" + companyFilter;
```

This does

```
String sqlComStr = "SELECT Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_Address1, Company_Address2, Company_Address3, Company_Suburb, Company_City, " +
    "Company_State, Company_PostCode, Company_Phone, Company_Fax, Company_WebsiteUrl, Company_Status, Company_ModifiedByUser_ID, Company_CreatedByUser_ID, " +
    " User_LoginName " +
    "FROM Company INNER JOIN [User] ON [User].User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID WHERE [Company].isDeleted = 0" + companyFilter;
```

....

```
String sqlComStr = "SELECT Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_Address1,    Company_Address2, Company_Address3, Company_Suburb, Company_City, " +
    "Company_State, Company_PostCode, Company_Phone, Company_Fax, Company_WebsiteUrl, Company_Status, Company_ModifiedByUser_ID, Company_CreatedByUser_ID, " +
    " [U1].User_LoginName " +
    "FROM Company INNER JOIN [User] AS U1 ON [User].User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID WHERE [Company].isDeleted = 0" + companyFilter;

sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlComStr;
sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source='PTSSHM\\SQLEXPRESS'; Initial Catalog='PROACTIVE'; Integrated Security=True;";
//sqlCon.ConnectionString = App.appSqlConnectionString;
sqlcmd.Connection = sqlCon;

try
{
    sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
    // If no Exception thrown at this point clear the quote items
    companys.Clear();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    // Read each row and create a new quite item object int he quoteitems list
    {
        companys.Add(new Company((int)sqlReader["Company_ID"],
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Name"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Address1"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Address2"].ToString(), 
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Address3"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Suburb"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_City"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_State"].ToString(),       
            (string)sqlReader["Company_PostCode"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Phone"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Fax"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_WebsiteUrl"].ToString(),
            (string)sqlReader["Company_Status"].ToString(),
            (int)sqlReader["Company_ModifiedByUser_ID"],
            (int)sqlReader["Company_CreatedByUser_ID"],
            (string)sqlReader["[U1].User_LoginName"].ToString(), "d"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to format all of your code snippets as code. Extracting the queries from the C# source to provide pure SQL-Queries would make it easier for others to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an alias for a table name such as User as U1, then the name [user] no longer exists for the query, you must use U1 on all of the subsequent references to it.

```
INNER JOIN [User] AS U1 ON [User].User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID
```

You are still using User in the join clause,

```
INNER JOIN [User] AS U1 ON U1.User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed

```
String sqlComStr = "SELECT Company_ID, Company_Name, Company_Address1, Company_Address2, Company_Address3, Company_Suburb, Company_City, " +
            "Company_State, Company_PostCode, Company_Phone, Company_Fax, Company_WebsiteUrl, Company_Status, Company_ModifiedByUser_ID, Company_CreatedByUser_ID, " +
            " [CreateUser].User_LoginName AS CreateUser, [ModUser].User_LoginName AS ModUser  " +
            "FROM Company INNER JOIN [User] As [CreateUser] ON [CreateUser].User_ID = [Company].Company_CreatedByUser_ID INNER JOIN [User] AS [ModUser] ON [ModUser].User_ID = [Company].Company_ModifiedByUser_ID WHERE [Company].isDeleted = 0" + companyFilter;
```

and

```
companys.Add(new Company((int)sqlReader["Company_ID"], (string)sqlReader["Company_Name"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_Address1"].ToString(),
                    (string)sqlReader["Company_Address2"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_Address3"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_Suburb"].ToString(),
                    (string)sqlReader["Company_City"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_State"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_PostCode"].ToString(),
                    (string)sqlReader["Company_Phone"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_Fax"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["Company_WebsiteUrl"].ToString(),
                    (string)sqlReader["Company_Status"].ToString(), (int)sqlReader["Company_ModifiedByUser_ID"], (int)sqlReader["Company_CreatedByUser_ID"],
                    (string)sqlReader["CreateUser"].ToString(), (string)sqlReader["ModUser"].ToString()));
```